# Wiring change 4 prong to 3 prong

Tags: electrical-panel

Can I change a 4 prong wiring to a 3 prong on a washer/dryer combo? Would it be the same procedure as it would be if it was just a 240 volt dryer?

Comment: Do you have the make/model of said washer/dryer combo?  Can you turn off the washer/dryer breaker, open up the outlet box for said washer/dryer, pull out the outlet (without taking any wires off), and post a photo of the inside of the box for that matter?

Comment: So your outlet is a 3 prong 240v ? Just want to make sure we are thinking correctly. If outlet is 4 prong I would agree with Harper's answer below. If the outlet is 3 prong it can be done legally because the home's wiring would be grandfathered and you could use 3 prong.

Comment: My washer/dryer is a Whirlpool thin twin stacked unit. It came with a 4 prong plug. My existing receptacle is 3 prong. I want to put a 3 prong cord on it to match my current receptacle. Thanks Paul

Answer (score 1):

The new code requires that all 240-volt residential appliances that require a neutral to also have a separate properly sized ground wire present as well.

Comment: Although code requires this on new construction the home is grandfathered and if built with 3 wire it is still legal to use today.

Answer (score 1):

You would never do that.  Instead, you would change the cord on the dryer to 4-prong.

Changing the dryer cord is a straightforward procedure, and it can be done safely without any risk of exposure to power.

The 3-prong connection is obsolete and hazardous, and was outlawed 20 years ago in new construction and remodels. I'm sure your dryer was first installed into an older home that had one, and at the time, its factory 4-prong cord was changed to a 3-prong.  Change it back.

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be two meanings to this question.

> Can I change a 4 prong wiring to a 3 prong **on** a washer/dryer
>   combo?

If @P Lentz is saying the cord on the combo washer/dryer is a 4 wire and he wants to change it to a 3 wire. **Then the answer would be no** since the 4 wire cord is indicating that 120/240V power and a neutral is needed. Therefore it cannot be connected to a 3 prong receptacle 240V power since that receptacle configuration does not support  a 120/240V connection without violating the current NEC.

Comment: How would I need to do to change my receptacle to a 4 prong. If I understand it my washer requires 120 volt and dryer 240. I have an existing 3 prong 240 volt receptacle. The new unit has a 4 prong cord.

Comment: @PLentz does your existing outlet have 4 conductors? After turning the power off to the outlet you need to remove the cover and perhaps the device to see if the are 4 conductors in the box, 2 - source conductors which measure 240V between them, 1 - white or neutral conductor and 1 - bare or green conductor which is the ground. If you do not, then you need to run a new set of conductors that do have 4 - conductors. Then you can connect a new 4 prong receptacle to the conductors.